# How do I search for a wildcard number in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

I want to search my excel worksheet for any string beginning with a single digit and a period and a space, but this isn't working:

```
Cells.Find(What:="[0-9]. ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
```

Runtime error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set.

Answer (score 0):

.Find does not allow to use such searching, use this method:

```
Sub test()
Dim ocell As Range, Result$
For Each ocell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If ocell.Value Like "[0-9. ]*" Then
        Result = Result & ocell.Address & Chr(10)
    End If
Next
MsgBox Result
End Sub
```